# MySql date range query not showing all records

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on mysql query right now. I write a query from fetch data from march 2018 to march 2019. There are more than 5000 records for this year. I write a query with date range from march 2018 to march 2019 but its showing me only 150 records

**One more thing here. The date column in database is varchar.**

Here is the query I created

```
SELECT a.*,b.
FROM OrderCalculation a
RIGHT JOIN crm_order b
   ON a.orderid = b.orderno
WHERE
    str_to_date(b.Date,'%Y-%m-%d') >= str_to_date(concat(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-08-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')-INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND
    str_to_date(b.Date,'%Y-%m-%d') <= str_to_date(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-08-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Right joins are very unusual (not wrong necessarily but avoided because they are more difficult to understand and therefore less easy to maintain)

Comment: For dates in an SQL query use BETWEEN instead of <= and >=, syntax is simple and reads better, WHERE test_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date

Comment: @SPlatten I try with between also not getting all the records.

Comment: How can we answer this? You have provided a non working query and not provided any indication of how your tables are designed or how they are linked or any sample data for us to work with.

Comment: @azadchauhan, then I suggest your dates are wrong or the order which you are using them is incorrect, BETWEEN works, I've used it for years.

Comment: @SPlatten yes it was issue with date format and Tim Biegeleisen solve my issue. See his answer. Thank you

Comment: @azadchauhan, again, use BETWEEN for dates, this is exactly what its for, more readable.  Without BETWEEN, you have to specify the date twice with two conditions, using BETWEEN, you specify the date once and then the two dates to compare with.

Comment: okay sure I will use BETWEEN Now with the answer of time not less and greater operators

Comment: @azadchauhan, you can also use BETWEEN to compare any value between a range, this includes numerical values and date/times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be storing dates as text.  That being said, your current calls to `STR_TO_DATE` are incorrect, because your date format is `dd-mm-YYYY`, not `YYYY-mm-dd`.  Try the following query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM crm_order a
LEFT JOIN OrderCalculation b
    ON a.orderid = b.orderno
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(b.Date, '%d-%m-%Y') >= '2018-03-01' AND
    STR_TO_DATE(b.Date, '%d-%m-%Y') < '2019-04-01';
```

If instead you want all data for the past year before the first of the current month, then try:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM crm_order a
LEFT JOIN OrderCalculation b
    ON a.orderid = b.orderno
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(b.Date, '%d-%m-%Y') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND
    STR_TO_DATE(b.Date, '%d-%m-%Y') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01');
```

Comment: Add some sample data to your question.  I don't see a problem with my answer.

Comment: date is saving in database in this format 01-04-2018 and it is varchar

Comment: @azadchauhan I assumed your current code is correct, and therefore assumed the wrong date format.  Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Tim its working now getting all the records now